# React: npx create-react-app vs referenciar .js

Tags: react

Qual diferença na hora de trabalhar com `React`, em usar o comando `npx create-react-app APP` ao simplesmente criar um arquivo `html` e referenciar as bibliotecas via script (.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diferença é que o comando faz tudo para você: cria os diretórios e arquivos, instala pacotes, faz a configuração inicial e entrega o projeto pronto para iniciar.

Depois de um tempo criando os mesmos arquivos, incluindo as mesmas referências e instalando os mesmos pacotes a cada novo projeto, você desejará usar o comando. ;)

Caso queira mais detalhes sobre o comando, [veja este link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).

Comment: Então se eu simplesmente incluir os .JS manualmente, funcionará também?

Comment: Sim, mas você precisará instalar os pacotes necessários e realizar as importações e configurações necessárias antes de iniciar o projeto.

Comment: Mas para um simples Hello World também?

Comment: Luhhh, depende. Se você não irá utilizar todos os recursos disponíveis do React, não é necessário. Mas, se você irá fazer um simples Hello World sem utilizar os diversos recursos do React (como rotas, por exemplo), por que utilizar o React? Para ver como adicionar o React em um projeto já existente, veja [esse link](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).